# number of ways of inviting 6 friends in a group of 3 for 5 days

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A person has 6 friends. Each evening, for 5 days, he or she invites 3
>   of them so the same group is never invited twice. How many ways are
>   there to do this?

My approach is : Number of ways of selecting 3 friends out of 6 is 20 (6 choose 3). Now out of these 20 groups, for the first night I can choose any one group in 20 ways. For the second night I can choose a group in 19 ways and so on. So the answer should be 20+19+18+17+16 = 90. Although I am not sure about this. 
 Is this the correct solution or am I doing something wrong here? 
P.S- this is question from mathematical circle and solution is not available for this.

Comment: You are close: you should be multiplying instead of adding.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16$. To understand why just think about this, for EACH group you can choose the first day you have 19 options the day after (and so on), so you have $20\cdot 19$ ways of chosing the groups of the first two days.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ${{6 \choose 3} \choose 5} = {20 \choose 5}$ ?